# How to create multiple columns based on a particular column in a table with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table that is generated by the attendance software in which all of the synced data from the biometric device will be stored.

```
ID | CHECKTIME
1  | 2023-08-01 07:22:30
1  | 2023-08-01 12:01:00
1  | 2023-08-01 12:43:00
1  | 2023-08-01 17:18:00
1  | 2023-08-02 05:13:30
1  | 2023-08-02 12:04:00
1  | 2023-08-02 12:33:00
1  | 2023-08-02 20:00:01
2  | 2023-08-01 06:11:30
2  | 2023-08-01 12:22:00
2  | 2023-08-01 12:53:00
2  | 2023-08-01 19:32:00
2  | 2023-08-02 07:11:30
2  | 2023-08-02 12:24:00
2  | 2023-08-02 12:37:00
2  | 2023-08-02 21:03:00
```

What I want to achieve is that from the table above to the table below, based on the following conditions.

```
AM_IN  = CHECKTIME BETWEEN '01:00' AND '08:00'
AM_OUT = CHECKTIME BETWEEN '12:01' AND '12:30'
PM_IN  = CHECKTIME BETWEEN '12:31' AND '13:00'
PM_OUT = CHECKTIME BETWEEN '13:01' AND '23:59'
```

```
ID | CHECKDATE  | AM_IN    | AM_OUT   | PM_IN    | PM_OUT   | 
1  | 2023-08-01 | 07:22:30 | 12:01:00 | 12:43:00 | 17:18:00 |
1  | 2023-08-02 | 05:13:30 | 12:04:00 | 12:33:00 | 20:00:01 |
2  | 2023-08-01 | 06:11:30 | 12:22:00 | 12:53:00 | 19:32:00 |
2  | 2023-08-02 | 07:11:30 | 12:24:00 | 12:37:00 | 21:03:00 |
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried anything???  SO is not a free coding service website.

Comment: The data includes seconds. What happens to CHECKTIMES in the gaps such as between 12:30 and 12:31 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of CASE expressions to derive your columns. So some code like below will give you what you want to achieve.

```
WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT ID
       , CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) AS SWIPEDATE
       , CASE WHEN CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) BETWEEN '01:00' AND '08:00' THEN 
       , CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) END AS AM_IN,
       , CASE WHEN CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:01' AND '12:30' THEN 
       , CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) END AS AM_OUT,
       , CASE WHEN CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:31' AND '13:00' THEN 
       , CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) END AS PM_IN,
       , CASE WHEN CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) BETWEEN '13:01' AND '23:59' THEN 
       , CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME) END AS PM_OUT
    FROM MyBiometricData
)

SELECT ID
       , SWIPEDATE,
       , MAX(AM_IN) AS AM_IN
       , MAX(AM_OUT) AS AM_OUT
       , MAX(PM_IN) AS PM_IN
       , MAX(PM_OUT) AS PM_OUT
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
       , SWIPEDATE
ORDER BY ID
       , SWIPEDATE;
```

There might be different ways of approaching the problem if you can state what your eventual goal is.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* **NOT** a *statement*!

Comment: A variation on this would be a CheckPeriod table with columns for the CheckPeriodName, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd. Join this to the table with the CHECKTIME using a BETWEEN condition. Then the MAX calculation uses a GROUP BY on the CheckPeriodName. Follow this with w PIVOT to display in columns. The main advantage of this technique is the classifications can be changed by changing values in the table rather than the query. It is also likely to perform faster.